# c++ hash_multimap how to get the values

Tags: c++, hash, multimap

This is probably really simple, but I can't find a simple example for it.
I understand that with a hash_multimap you can have several values mapped to a single key. But how exactly would I access those values. All the examples I stumbled across always just access the first value mapped to the the key. Heres an example of what I mean

```
key : value
1 : obj1a;
2 : obj2a, obj2b, obj2c
```

how would I access obj2b and obj2c, not just obj2a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual multimap iteration loop is like this:

```
#include <unordered_multimap>

typedef std::unordered_multimap<K, V> mmap_t;

mmap_t m;

for (mmap_t::const_iterator it1 = m.begin(), it2 = it1, end = m.end(); it1 != end; it1 = it2)
{
    // outer loop over unique keys

    for ( ; it1->first == it2->first; ++it2)
    {
        // inner loop, all keys equal to it1->first
    }
}
```

To iterate over just one key value, use [`equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap/equal_range) instead.

```
std::pair<mmap_t::const_iterator, mmap_t::const_iterator> p = m.equal_range(key);

for (mmap_t::const_iterator it = p.first; it != p.second; ++it)
{
    // use "it->second"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For example, `equal_range` returns an two iterators, to the begin and end of the matching range :

```
void lookup(const map_type& Map, int key)
{
  cout << key << ": ";
  pair<map_type::const_iterator, map_type::const_iterator> p =
    Map.equal_range(key);

  for (map_type::const_iterator i = p.first; i != p.second; ++i)
    cout << (*i).second << " ";

  cout << endl;
}
```

where we're using a `map_type` like

```
class ObjectT; // This is the type of object you want to store
typedef hash_multimap<int, ObjectT> map_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just grab an iterator to the first one and increment it. If the keys are still equal, you've got another entry with the same key value. You can also use [equal_range](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal_range/).